# mysql set a flag for each match

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT users_extra.first_name, users_extra.last_name
FROM (branches, users_extra)
WHERE ((branches.manager_id = users_extra.userid)
OR (branches.sales_manager_id = users_extra.userid)
OR (branches.admin_manager_id = users_extra.userid)
OR (branches.ops_manager_id = users_extra.userid)
OR (branches.export_manager_id = users_extra.userid)
OR (branches.import_manager_id = users_extra.userid))
AND branches.branch_id = [$VAR]
```

How do i return the column name or some sort of flag for each match so i can return the position of each manager, eg:

```
first_name, last_name, position
joe         soap       manager
john        doe        ops manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CASE WHEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) in the SELECT part.

```
SELECT users_extra.first_name, users_extra.last_name,
    CASE users_extra.userid
    WHEN branches.manager_id THEN 'manager'
    WHEN branches.sales_manager_id  THEN 'sales manager'
    ...
    END AS position
FROM ...
```